# STM32L1 - How do the Cat.1 vs Cat.2 (etc.) lables relate to the part numbers?

Tags: stm32

I am looking at the [data sheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00240193.pdf) for the STM32L1 and I keep seeing references to Cat.1, Cat.2, ... etc. devices.  How do those categories relate to the part numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting on page 40 of the reference manual (section 1.4 "Product category definition"), you will see a set of handy tables that will correlate your device to its category number.

Comment: thanks, couldn't figure it out. This must be the only company which has datasheets to it's datasheets.